# Comparing date in django queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a query string which i am using to get all archived (passed) meetings

like

```
 get_meetings =  Meeting.objects.filter(created_by = user_id.id,meeting_datetime__lte =  datetime.now())
```

here is the model structure

```
 meeting_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now,blank=True, null=True)
```

the above query is returning all meetings which is going to be happen on 29 december also .

I want the details of all meetings before now .

PLease tell me what i am doing wrong here  >

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. could you give some more code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get strict condition you should use [less than `__lt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#lt) instead "less equal than". Also, to avoid include meetings day, you can get "first minute day":

```
today_min = datetime.datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.time.min)
get_meetings = ( Meeting
                .objects
                .filter(created_by = user_id.id,
                        meeting_datetime__lt =  today_min
                       )
               )
```

Comment: could you explain why __lte seems to compare only the date of a dattime field? I checked this with datetime.now() < datetime.now(), which seemed to work as you would expect.

Comment: @farmerjack, thanks about your comment. After read it and reread OP post I have improved answer (I think). Would you check if my answer catch OP requirements now? Regards.

Comment: I should have edited my previous post, but when I tried to fully replicate the problem in django I couldn't. The OP code worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`lte` means `less than or equal to` you need `lt` which means `less than`

```
get_meetings =  Meeting.objects.filter(created_by__id = user_id.id,
                                       meeting_datetime__lt=datetime.now())
```